# MySQL SELECT database entries with the same column value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the fallowing database table 'table_name':

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| ID | user_id | meta_key1    |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 |    d         |
|  2 |       1 |    f         |
|  3 |       1 |    c         | 
|  4 |       2 |    g         | 
|  5 |       3 |    1         |
|  6 |       3 |    2         |
|  7 |       4 |    4         | 
|  8 |       4 |    5         | 
|  9 |       4 |    5         |
| 10 |       4 |    5         |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

I would like to select * from all entries where the user_id = '1'.

The code I'm using now returns only the first value:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

while($row){
    return $row["meta_key1"];
}
```

The result is always the first entry from the table_name where the user_id='(given_id)':

```
d
```

While I'd like this result:

```
d
f
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);){
    echo $row["meta_key1"];
}
```

Currently, you only call `mysql_fetch_assoc` one time.
You need to call it every time you need the next row.

Comment: Tried, no changes, the returned result is the first entry from the table_name.

Comment: Look closely, I changed `return` by `echo`. When you return the first value, for sure you won't have next one, you're no longer in the function. Please have a look on @nickb post, who explains how to return all rows in an array.

Answer (score 5):

You need to continually fetch a row in the loop to get every row in the result, similar to this:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row["meta_key1"];
}
```

Since you were doing `return $row['meta_key1']`, as soon as the first row was fetched, the function returned with one value. So, if you're using this in a function, you'll need to build an array to get all of the values:

```
$return = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $return[] = $row["meta_key1"];
}
return $return;
```

Comment: Tried. The same result returned.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe - Try again `:)`

Comment: It worked, thank you. I've been so much focused on the function itself that I simply overlooked that the `return` statement exits the function.